# Hangouts/Chat - messagesUnread always 0 despite new messages

Tags: google-hangouts

I'm trying to write a Hangouts/Chat dockapp to show unread message notifications, I'm using the following scope url:

https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/labels/CHAT?access_token=<my_access_token>

The json returns fine, however messagesUnread is always 0. I've disconnected every possible app/browser etc that could be grabbing the messages before I reloaded the above URL, sent a new chat message from another account and messagesTotal increments by 1 but still the unread stays at 0. Even if I disable hangouts in the gmail web interface settings, send a message and search by "label:chat" the chat message that was received arrives marked as read in the web interface. If I manually mark a chat message as unread then the values in the above url do change correctly.

I can obviously work around this by storing he previous messagesTotal on comparing to current, however that creates a requirement to click the app to acknowledge the unreads which is a tad annoying.

Has anyone found a way to get a true unread count from chats/hangouts?

Thanks,

Haydn.

Answer (score 0):

- If you use the method [users.labels.get](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.labels/get) for any other label (e.g. `INBOX`), it will return `messagesUnread` correctly.
- Unfortunately for the label `CHAT` this is not the case
- Chat messages are not quite the same as emails
- It is not clear either it is intended behavior that you cannot retrieve the unread chat messages or a bug
- This issue has been already [filed](https://issuetracker.google.com/163386752) on Google's Public Issue Tracker, but it has been closed by Google because it has been reported in Spanish.
- Feel free to report the issue in English to hopefully obtain a response from Google eihter the bheavior is intended or a bug.

Comment: Thanks, I've submitted an English version (that's an odd reason to close a ticket, I mean surely Google know how to use Google translate right?? :P). I get the feeling the bug isn't an inaccurate messagesUnread count, it looks like the messages are being sent/received already marked as read, even searching the gmail web interface for "label:chat" shows messages you've just received and never read already marked as read. Anyway, bug link for reference: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/169647708